# How does glmnet standardize variables when weights are present?

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet

glmnet allows the user to input a vector of observation weights through the `weights` argument. glmnet also standardizes (by default) the predictor variables to have zero mean and unit variance. My question is: when `weights` is provided, does glmnet standardize the predictors using the weighted mean (and standard deviation) of each column or the unweighted mean (and standard deviation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a description of `glmnet`'s standardization at [Link](https://thinklab.com/discussion/computing-standardized-logistic-regression-coefficients/205#5)

In the post you can see the Fortran-Code-Snippet of `glmnet`'s source that computes the standardization. ("Proof" paragraph, second bullet).

I'm not familiar with Fortran, but to me it looks very much like it is in fact using the *weighted* mean and sd.

Edit: From the glmnet vignette:

> "`weights` is for the observation weights. Default is 1 for each
>   observation. (Note: glmnet rescales the weights to sum to N, the
>   sample size.)"

With `w` in the Fortran code being the rescaled weights, this seems to be consistent with *weighted mean standardization*.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, consistent with the accepted answer, the weights in `glmnet` are sampling weights, and not inverse variance weights. For example if you have many more observations than *unique* observations, you can compress your dataset and get the same coefficient estimates:

```
n <- 50
m <- 5

y_norm <- rnorm(n)
y_bool <- rbinom(n,1,.5)
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*m),n)
w <- rpois(n,3) + 1 # weights
w_indx <- rep(1:n,times=w) # weights index

m1 = glmnet(x, y_norm, weights = w)
m2 = glmnet(x[w_indx,] ,y_norm[w_indx])
all.equal(coef(m1,s=.1),
          coef(m2,s=.1))
>>> TRUE

M1 = glmnet(x,y_bool,weights = w,family = "binomial")
M2 = glmnet(x[w_indx,],y_bool[w_indx],family = "binomial")
all.equal(coef(M1,s=.1),
          coef(M2,s=.1))
>>> TRUE
```

Of course, a bit more care needs to be used when using weights with cv.glmnet since the weights of aggregated records should be spread across folds using a multinomial distribution...